# Fluid Typolink ViewHelper ignores additionalParams-attribute

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x, typolink

I want to create a link to an external page with parameters via the f:link.typolink-ViewHelper. The ViewHelper creates the link but without my parameters. I've used an example from the TYPO3 documentation (https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Link/Typolink.html). I'm using TYPO3 9.5. Do I need some further configuration?

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="www.test-link.de" additionalParams="&u=b">
   Linktext
</f:link.typolink>
```

Comment: 2 things I noticed: its called *additional*Params but your target URL does not yet contain any other parameter (as does it in the example) and from the 7.6 docs: `Note: This is only active for internal links! ` I'm not sure if that has changed in 9.5 as the description there is just empty

Comment: Thats the wrong viewhelper for this. Whats your goal here? Are the parameters dynamic so a viewhelper is actually needed? You might wanna take a look at https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Uri/Typolink.html

Comment: I would suggest this one: https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Link/External.html

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to write this would be:

```
additionalParams="{name: 'value'}"
```

You can even combine multiple parameters like this:

```
additionalParams="{name: 'value', anotherName: 'anotherValue'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It can work without additionalParams

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="www.test-link.de?u=b" >
   Linktext
</f:link.typolink>
```

FYI, additionalParams was not working of me as well. So I did the above

Update:
There is documentation error at https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/10.4/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Link/Typolink.html

Way to do it is as suggested by @Scopestyle